# Need to count two separate values in one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I'm trying to get the sums of two separate values to appear in one row, per unique ID. I've tried a couple routes but still can't get everything to appear in one row. I've tried a few different ways of using case statements and I've tried using OVER with partitions, as well, to no avail.

Here is my query so far:

```
select distinct ID_NUM, 
  sum(case when isnull(sch.SUBTERM_CDE,0) like '%N' then 1 else 0 end) as 'total_n',
  sum(case when isnull(sch.SUBTERM_CDE,0) like '%T' then 1 else 0 end) as 'total_t'
from STUDENT_CRS_HIST sch
where sch.END_DTE > GETDATE()
group by sch.ID_NUM, sch.SUBTERM_CDE
order by ID_NUM
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost right, but you are grouping by an extra column:

```
SELECT  ID_NUM, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN sch.SUBTERM_CDE LIKE '%N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_n,
        SUM(CASE WHEN sch.SUBTERM_CDE LIKE '%T' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_t
FROM STUDENT_CRS_HIST sch
WHERE sch.END_DTE > GETDATE()
GROUP BY sch.ID_NUM -- you shouldn't group by SUBTERM_CDE
ORDER BY ID_NUM
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! That grouping was residual from one of my previous efforts where sql yelled at me to include it :)

Answer (score 1):

Change the `group by` to remove `SUBTERM_CDE`:

```
select ID_NUM, 
       sum(case when sch.SUBTERM_CDE like '%N' then 1 else 0 end) as total_n,
       sum(case when sch.SUBTERM_CDE like '%T' then 1 else 0 end) as total_t
from STUDENT_CRS_HIST sch
where sch.END_DTE > GETDATE()
group by sch.ID_NUM
order by ID_NUM;
```

In addition:

- The `distinct` is unneeded and misleading.
- Column aliases should not be enclosed in single quotes (only use single quotes for string and date constants).
- The text for `NULL` is unnecessary -- and misleading.  The alternative value is an integer, but the field is supposedly a string.